# what's wrong with my servlet or browser?

Tags: http, servlets, http-headers

I installed an application at this URL: `http://localhost:8080/servlet/xml`.     The servlet supports two ways for passing arguments — as query string and as path info (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/servlet/xml?name =/test/my.xml` and `http://localhost:8080/servlet/xml/test/my.xml`).
It is designed to apply a default transformation to the referenced XML file that is located at the server, generate an HTML file, and send it back to the browser. Something is wrong, and even though the servlet generates exactly the html in both scenarios, the browser renders it as HTML in the first example and as XML in the second. Moreover, when I compare HTTP responses (including status codes, headers, and bodies) in these two cases, it turns out that they are identical. How is this possible? What is the problem with the servlet?

Comment: Do you have the content-type and content-disposition headers set properly? I think the browser is trying to infer the content type based on the URL here.

Comment: Sounds very much like setting up content-type properly would solve this. @adarshr I think you should post this as an answer.

Comment: This might as well be a browser setting. Do you observe the problem only in a particular browser (e.g. IE) or have you tried all ones (e.g. Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Opera/etc)?

Comment: yes I tried all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the content type of the response properly? For HTML you should do as follows:

```
response.setContentType("text/html")
```